# why it seems stop endlessly,when execute java code "BufferedReader readLine()"

Tags: java, android, adb

I create a java application project.It can push the specified files in one folder to android's sdcard by using adb order.But,I find that when it execute readLine method in BufferedReader.It will be blocked,the "System.out.println("runCmd::inBr toString::"+inBr.readLine());" code  export nothing.And it will be ok when push one file not folder if it contains more files.
  Need Help:how should I do,it will export the results continually when execute code "System.out.println("the result is ::"+lineStr);"

```
`   public static int runCmd(String pcmd) {
    System.out.println(pcmd.toString());
    Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process process = run.exec("cmd.exe /c " + pcmd.toString());
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                process.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader inBr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        System.out.println("runCmd::inBr toString::"+inBr.readLine());
        String lineStr;
        while ((lineStr = inBr.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("the result is ::"+lineStr);
        }
        System.out.println("(lineStr = inBr.readLine()) != null---222--::"+lineStr);
        if (process.waitFor() != 0) {
            if (process.exitValue() == 1) {
                System.err.println("failed !");
                return RUN_CMD_FAILED_OTHER_REASON;
            }
        }
        inBr.close();
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return RUN_CMD_FAILED_OTHER_REASON;
    }
    return RUN_CMD_SUCCESSFUL;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    runCmd("adb push D:\\syncTool\\toMobileResPhoto"+ " " + "/mnt/sdcard/syncTool/toMobileResPhoto");
}
```

the result in cmd shell is :`C:\Users\Administrator>adb push D:\syncTool\toMobileResPhoto /mnt/sdcard/syncToo
l/toMobileResPhoto
push: D:\syncTool\toMobileResPhoto/kanhu_20_1384314535500.jpg -> /mnt/sdcard/syn
cTool/toMobileResPhoto/kanhu_20_1384314535500.jpg
push: D:\syncTool\toMobileResPhoto/gz_21_13843234984063.jpg -> /mnt/sdcard/syncT
ool/toMobileResPhoto/gz_21_13843234984063.jpg
push: D:\syncTool\toMobileResPhoto/gz_21_13843234984062.jpg -> /mnt/sdcard/syncT
ool/toMobileResPhoto/gz_21_13843234984062.jpg
push: D:\syncTool\toMobileResPhoto/gz_21_13843234984061.jpg -> /mnt/sdcard/syncT
ool/toMobileResPhoto/gz_21_13843234984061.jpg
push: D:\syncTool\toMobileResPhoto/bgz_20_13844854120623.jpg -> /mnt/sdcard/sync
Tool/toMobileResPhoto/bgz_20_13844854120623.jpg
push: D:\syncTool\toMobileResPhoto/bgz_20_13844854120622.jpg -> /mnt/sdcard/sync
Tool/toMobileResPhoto/bgz_20_13844854120622.jpg
push: D:\syncTool\toMobileResPhoto/bgz_20_13844854120461.jpg -> /mnt/sdcard/sync
Tool/toMobileResPhoto/bgz_20_13844854120461.jpg
7 files pushed. 0 files skipped.
1469 KB/s (346069 bytes in 0.230s)`

Comment: Does the input string contain the new-line `\n` character? If not, the `BufferedReader.readLine()` method will block "forever" (until the input provides the new-line character and a complete line can be returned by the method or until the end of the input stream has been reached, but the process stream seems not to match either of the two conditions).

Comment: what does the output look like when you run the command manually in a cmd shell?

Comment: thanks for your answer,and please refer to lastest  describe.